# How to add virtual directores and allow access to pages in Apache server?

Tags: apache, apache2

I know this is a repeated question but Im totally blocked with no understanding of creating virtual directories for apache server

I'm able access my homepage `index.html` but I'm unable to access another page in that folder
`page2.html` in `/var/www/html/`

Also I need to view the folder `Firmwares` soft-linked to another folder in desktop.
I'm using Fedora 14

Here are my questions
1. How can enable access to other pages in `/var/www/html/`?
2. What privileges must I provide that Folder and what changes in httpd.conf?
3. How can I just easily add a virtual directory? Do I have to edit the .conf file every time?
(Can I edit .conf file once and then create sub directories in the same parent folder without fuss?)

Current HTTPD.conf is -
http://pastebin.com/BBxaAhMk

Current Privileges are -

```
[root@wbserv ~]# ls -l /var/www/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root 4096 Jul 26  2010 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root      root 4096 Jan 25 17:23 error
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root 4096 Feb 14 04:41 html
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root      root 4096 Jan 25 17:26 icons
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root      root 4096 Jan 25 17:27 manual
drwxr-xr-x.  2 webalizer root 4096 Feb  7 03:39 usage
[root@wbserv ~]# ls -l /var/www/html/
total 868
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  52264 Feb  6 15:48 bkg.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 462993 Feb  6 15:48 banner.png
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  28785 Feb  6 15:48 title.png
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     24 Feb 10 15:39 Firmwares -> /root/Desktop/Firmwares/
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   6282 Feb 14 04:39 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   9304 Feb  6 15:48 logo.png
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  16877 Feb  6 15:48 sorttable.js
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   1432 Feb 14 04:39 page2.html
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   4303 Feb  6 15:48 style.css

[root@wbserv ~]# ls -l /root/Desktop/
total 16
drwx------.  4 root root 4096 Jan 31 15:28 Firmwares
drwx------. 10 root root 4096 Feb 14 04:36 Utilities
```

Comment: Your configuration looks ok for what you are trying to accomplish. The reason you can't access files in your Firmware directory is that apache user and/or group don't have permissions to read the dir. Also, I don't see any problems with accessing other files but the index.html file in your document root dir (/var/www/html). What error did you get if you try to access page2.html?

Comment: I got access to page2.html by putting it into another folder `/var/www/html/p2/page2.html`. How do I enable apache access to Firmwares folder?